# What does "stay on task" mean?

Tags: meaning, articles

It is from this [video](https://youtu.be/UMDx83NeXNA). It is at around 2 minute and 25 second. Here is the context:

> Another group of researchers took a look at the evidence out there in 2013, and concluded that habitually eating breakfast did help children to **stay on task** in school.

Does this mean it helps them to stay concentrated on their task, or it helps them to do it? If I am right, then why was an article omitted before the word *task*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"stay on task" means "stay focused".

> Note that the speaker emphasizes "stay focused", not the
>   specific task.

So, you talk about "task"  *in general*, and you don’t need an article when you talk about things in general:

> There are many reasons why a kindergartner might not be able to stay
>   *on task* in the classroom.
>
> My manager instructs me to pay attention *on work*.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct; "Stay on Task" means to stay focused or to maintain concentration.

The reason there is no article in front of the word Task is that "stay on task" is a well-known *phrase* and does not follow the normal rules of grammar.

Comment: Your explanation of the meaning is fine. But the phrase does follow normal rules.  Compare: on point, on course, on topic, on time, on deck, on assignment, on vacation, on holiday, on hiatus.